# How to change the Wordpress Elementor dropdown ul display value from block to grid

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, elementor

I am using Astra theme with elementor plugin.

How i can change the dropdown ul item css value for display-> (from block to grid)? i tried to add the custome css code but its not working.

```
.elementor-nav-menu--dropdown {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;

}
```

I tried to add the jquery in bottom of the footer.php above the body tag but its not working as well. the code is not even pulled to the website.

```
<script>
if($('.elementor-nav-menu--dropdown').visible{
  ($('.elementor-nav-menu--dropdown').css('display','grid')
};
</script>
```

And i tried adding to the custom code from elementor plugin, its throwing an erorr "$ is not function".

```
<script>
if($('.elementor-nav-menu--dropdown').visible{
  ($('.elementor-nav-menu--dropdown').css('display','grid')
};
</script>
```

Currently when the dropdown is visible the display has been changed to "block" but i want to set the display value to "grid".

Comment: `visible{` in your jquery is not valid. It will either be `visible('display','grid')` or `visible({'display':'grid'})`

Answer (score 0):

Elementor uses a jQuery library called [Smartmenus](https://www.smartmenus.org/docs/) to build the dropdown menu. To change the behavior of the menu, you can override the Smartmenus with your own code.

This is an example that worked on my code. In my case, I needed to change display: block into display: flex, but I think it will work if you change to display: grid as well.

You can check their [documentation](https://www.smartmenus.org/docs/) to change other behaviors you need.

```html
    $(".elementor-nav-menu").on("show.smapi", function (e, menu) {
        const newCSS = `
            width: auto;
            min-width: 10em;
            display: grid;
            max-width: 1000px;
            margin-left: 0px;
        `;
        menu.setAttribute("style", newCSS);
    });
```